# Is it possible to skip onPause() method of BaseActivity in MainActivity when latter extends former?

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActiviy extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        // Can I avoid BaseActivity's onPause()?
    }
}
```

I just want to call `onPause()` in `MainActivity` skipping `BaseActivity`.

I cannot edit `BaseActivity` as it is part of a library that I'm using and removing `super.onPause()` in `MainActivity` gives error.

Maybe this is possible or maybe not so workarounds are most welcome.

Comment: Are you asking if you can call the grandparent's onPause instead?  Even if you could it would be NOT recommended-  if the parent depends on its onPause being called, you'd break everything later on.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I want to call grandparent's onPause. I understand that it's not recommended but I'm willing to take that risk for now.

Comment: It isn't possible.  If you could edit BaseActivity you could hack something in.   But without that, not really.

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' It would throw an exception, as its a lifecycle method that must be called.  You could catch the exception but then things would break.